# Get data from ui-select2 --> Inputsearch textbox And save in database

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2

I am using ui-select2 .
I want to access "search text box" value .
How i can do that?

Are there events for this textbox?

Answer (score 0):

just use the ng-model reference like (fm.sexual_habits.std_history). it will be an array:

```
<select multiple="multiple" ui-select2 ng-model="fm.sexual_habits.std_history" class="">
                        <option value="Chancroid">Chancroid</option>
                        <option value="Chlamydia">Chlamydia</option>
                        <option value="Genital Wart">Genital Warts</option>
                        <option value="Gonorrhea">Gonorrhea</option>
                        <option value="Hepatitis B">Hepatitis B</option>
                        <option value="Herpes">Herpes</option>
                        <option value="HIV & AIDS">HIV & AIDS</option>
                        <option value="Human Papillomaviru">Human Papillomavirus</option>
                        <option value="Molluscum Contagiosum">Molluscum Contagiosum</option>
                        <option value="PID">PID</option>
                        <option value="Pubic Lice">Pubic Lice</option>
                        <option value="Scabies">Scabies</option>
                        <option value="Syphilis">Syphilis</option>
                        <option value="Trichomoniasis">Trichomoniasis</option>
                    </select>
```